# Getting the right data from my object to execute a sum in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to get an attribute from an array I have, but I can't seem to do it.

In my .ts archive I'm calling my backend endpoint and getting this data:

```
export class PostFeedComponent implements OnInit {
  data: any = {};

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { 
    this.getItems();
    this.getPosts();
  }

  getItems() {
    return this.http.get(`${environment.apiBaseUrl}/getPosts`);
  }

  getPosts () {
    this.getItems().subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);
      this.data = data
    })
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

The console log I have in the getPosts() method returns this: (from my chrome console)

```
Object
post: Array(4)
0:
calories: 567
description: "Arroz tres delicias cocinado con salsa de soja"
eatenAt: "04/26/2019"
foodName: "Arroz tres delicias"
foodUuid: "f64718fa-a29a-4627-8744-9521133e03f0"
pictureUrl: null
_id: "5ccf85d73e4afe354d7a6b23"
__proto__: Object
1: {eatenAt: "May 6, 2019 2:57 AM", _id: "5ccf869e4f853735a4a4682b", foodUuid: "90172850-da39-4f76-a212-4dd1cb3594e3", pictureUrl: null, foodName: "Cacahuetes", …}
2: {eatenAt: "May 6, 2019", _id: "5ccf8778c9d4713602440cb9", foodUuid: "cab3a696-ef37-4dca-b088-c66c7c8cf79b", pictureUrl: null, foodName: "Azull", …}
3: {eatenAt: "May 6, 2019", _id: "5ccf8800c9d4713602440cba", foodUuid: "724c26da-51d9-426e-b2ad-bfe8665bba0a", pictureUrl: null, foodName: "patucos", …}
length: 4
```

So what I want to do is access the "calories" attribute in my arrays and  add them up to get a total of calories, however, I don't know how to refer to them in my .ts code. When I write it like this in my html it works tho:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let post of data.post; let i=index;">
    <p>{{post.calories}}</p>
</ng-container>
```

The mongoose schema I'm calling from backend:

```
const trackingPostSchema = new Schema({
    uuid: {
        type: String,
        unique: true,
      },
    post: [{
        foodUuid: String,
        pictureUrl: String,
        foodName: String,
        description: String,
        calories: Number,
        eatenAt: {
            type: String,
            default: date,
        },
        mealTime: String, //breakfast, lunch, dinner
    }],
  });
```

and I'm sending it from node like this:

```
'use strict'

const trackingPostModel = require('../../../models/tracking-post');

async function getPosts(req, res){

    const { uuid } = req.claims;

    try{
        const posts = await trackingPostModel.findOne({ uuid }, {_id: 0, __v: 0}).lean();

        return res.status(200).send(posts);
    }catch(e){
        return res.status(500).send(e.message);
    }
}

module.exports = getPosts;
```

The response I'm getting:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Powered-By: Express
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST,GET,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Location,Authorization,Content-Type
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Location,Authorization,Content-Type
Allow: GET,HEAD
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 8
ETag: W/"8-ZRAf8oNBS3Bjb/SU2GYZCmbtmXg"
Date: Mon, 06 May 2019 14:45:19 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
```

I've tried using data.post.calories, data.calories, data[i].calories, data.post[i].calories...etc. Destructuring as well, but I cant' catch it :/

Comment: could you please post the returned JSON?

Comment: The JSON from my endpoint? I'm using mongoose, this is my schema:

```

const trackingPostSchema = new Schema({
    uuid: {
        type: String,
        unique: true,
      },
    post: [{
        foodUuid: String,
        pictureUrl: String,
        foodName: String,
        description: String,
        calories: Number,
        eatenAt: {
            type: String,
            default: date,
        },
        mealTime: String, //breakfast, lunch, dinner
    }],
  });
```

Comment: [**Reserve the constructor for simple initialization such as wiring constructor parameters to properties. The constructor shouldn't do anything. It certainly shouldn't call a function that makes HTTP requests to a remote server as a real data service would.**](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4)

Comment: your console log shows that your items are set in an object as attributes not in an array - not sure what that `post` array really contains, you just showed us that this is an array of 4 elements

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that I expect your json to be something like this

```
{
 ...,
 post: [{
  calories: 123,
  ...
 }, ...]
}
```

You could try directly retrieving the sum of calories before subscription using RxJs pipe operators, something like this

```
export class PostFeedComponent implements OnInit {
    data: any = {};

    sum: number;

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    }

    getItems() {
        return this.http.get(`${environment.apiBaseUrl}/getPosts`);
    }

    getPosts () {
        this.getItems().pipe(
            tap(data => {
                // relevant part
                this.sum = data.post.map(p => {
                  return p.calories;
                }.reduce((a, b) => {
                    return a + b;
                }, 0)
            })
        ).subscribe(data => {
            console.log(data);
            this.data = data
        })
    }

    ngOnInit() {
      this.getItems();
      this.getPosts();
    }

}
```

and you will have set `this.sum` inside your component, without modifying anything else

Comment: Using this I get that "property reduce does not exist int type 'Object'"

Comment: so it's not directly an array, is `post` a property of root object? so is `object.post` is an array?

Comment: Thanks, but using that I come back to square one, where I get that post is not part of data...

Comment: @Hurrmer could you please update your question with your JSON? or your mongoose schema

Comment: Ok, saw it. how are you sending it back from node?

Comment: I updated the post with the code I'm using to send it

Comment: @Hurrmer let's continue on this [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192915/node-js-question-support)

Comment: I don't have enough reputation unfortunately haha

Comment: @Hurrmer ok, so please can you go to your browser's devtools's network tab and copy the http response you're getting? it should be a JSON

Comment: The response is "GET,HEAD". The full headers are:

Comment: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Powered-By: Express
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST,GET,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Location,Authorization,Content-Type
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Location,Authorization,Content-Type
Allow: GET,HEAD
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 8
ETag: W/"8-ZRAf8oNBS3Bjb/SU2GYZCmbtmXg"
Date: Mon, 06 May 2019 14:45:19 GMT
Connection: keep-alive

Comment: please update your answer with response body, it's kinda unreadable from comments :)

Comment: @Hurrmer sorry but it's not the returned JSON yet, that's the response headers, I need response body